# mini page for code in latex

Tags: latex

I would like to add my result from R code inside the latex. I understand that can be done easily using `lstlisting` package. However, I tried to make the code as two parts (side by side). I tried to use minipage with `lstlisting` but it does not work. Is there any easy way to have a mini-page with my code or the result of my work instead of doing that manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no problem with setting the `lstlisting` environments inside `minipage`s and have them side-by-side:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle = \ttfamily}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
Here is some code,
some more lines;
Interesting stuff ^;
More _ $ content.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
Output, stuff,
  and more stuff.$
Very !()@ interesting.
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help. It is really work very well. I tried it before but did not work. I think I used the code wrongly.

Comment: Yeh. I think I used the `\begin` and `\end` one time only for the whole code and that it was my problem.